# RegEx: Ignoring only characters that meet both lookahead and lookbehind

Tags: regex, ruby, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to parse a file in Ruby to make it valid JSON. It uses single quotes, so I need to replace those.

But it also uses single quotes as possessives in words. I'm trying to use regex to get only single quotes that don't have a letter before AND a letter after, but what I have so far is ignoring anything with a letter before OR a letter after.

RegEx `(?<![a-zA-Z])'(?![a-zA-Z])`

Test String `'id': '4da7680f-3449-303f-8e79-d2abe665cbe9', 'phone_numbers': ['4108286112']}]}, {'email': None, 'gender': '', 'first_name': None, 'id': 1659439495, 'last_name': None, 'middle_name': None, 'network_ids': [100494], 'organization_name': "CHARLOTTE'S HAIR LINE INC.", 'phone': '4109334800'`

Link: https://rubular.com/r/MDthi9TWEvLOip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following pattern:

```
'(?!(?<=[a-zA-Z]')[a-zA-Z])
```

See the [Rubular demo](https://rubular.com/r/AWFmDpZXtPhuCn)

**Details**

- `'` - a single quotation mark
- `(?!(?<=[a-zA-Z]')[a-zA-Z])` - a  negative lookahead that fails the match if, immediately to the right of the current location (after `'`), there is

  - `(?<=[a-zA-Z]')` - (a positive lookbehind matching) a location that is immediately preceded with an ASCII letter and `'`
  - `[a-zA-Z]` - an ASCII letter.